# Solution to the integral of Bessel $\int^1_0 x \sin(a x) J_1 (b x) dx$

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, special-functions, bessel-functions

I've been trying to work out the solution of this integral. I have seen in the Gradshteyn (**6.669**(9)) a similar integral:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 x^\nu \sin(a x)J_\nu(a x)dx= \frac{1}{2\nu+1}\left[\sin(a) J_\nu(a)-\cos(a) J_{\nu+1}(a) \right]
\end{equation}

But I'm looking for something in the form $\int_0^1 x^\nu \sin(a x)J_\nu(b x)dx$, particularly for the case $\nu = 1$. I've been trying to get a solution but I haven't got any luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, there doesn't appear to be a formula in [DMLF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22#ii) so your last chance is Watson..

Comment: I tried it with Mathematica, it can do the first integral but gives up on your variant.

Comment: there is no closed form solution; you could expand in powers of $a$ and obtain a series expansion...